# OpenCV: Making GPU pyrlk_optical_flow.cpp work on video input

Tags: opencv, gpu, opticalflow

It seems that the pyrlk_optical_flow.cpp sample code (opencv\samples\gpu) only works on two still images.

If so, do any of you know of examples of how to convert the code from still image input to streaming video or webcam input?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.